# JPA Specifications: Select items where list attribute contains item with certain value

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to solve the following problem with JPA specifications:

Consider the following classes:

```
public class Language {
    private String name;
    ...
}

public class Person {
    private List<Language> languages;
    ...
}
```

How do I select all `Person`s, that speak a language with name `x`? I am looking for a solution using the `CriteriaBuilder`, which should generate a `Predicate` that I can 'and' together with other predicates.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually pretty easy:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> root = query.from(Person.class);
ListJoin<Person, Language> langJoin = root.join(Person_.langs);
query.where(cb.equal(langJoin.get(Language_.name), lang));
```

So you basically join the languages via corresponding association and then add an `equals` predicate matching the required attribute of the joined entity with your criteria.

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't it be `joinList` instead of `join`?

Comment: `joinList` is not typesafe, as it relies on string name of the association. When you use `Root.join` and you pass in an attribute from entity metamodel, it will automatically return a corresponding join type, based on the metamodel attribute type. In our case `Person_.langs` is a `ListAttribute`, therefore the resulting join is 
 `ListJoin` instance- just have a look at all the overloaded `.join` methods.